# Как растянуть блок в html (или css)?

Tags: css, css3, html5, html-form

У меня есть html файл:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

     <h1>Tasks</h1>
       <div id="blog"><%= link_to "+", new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %></div>
</div>
```

есть CSS файл:

```
.col-md-12 {
  background-color: #4682B4;
  display: flex;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#blog {
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;

  transition: .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#blog:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

При запуске сервера получается следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мен растянуть блок в лева и в право

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 вариант:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>Tasks</h1>
        <div id="blog"><%= link_to "+", new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Добавьте родительский div .row

**2 вариант:**

```
<div class="col-md-12 fluid-block">
   <h1>Tasks</h1>
   <div id="blog">
       <%= link_to "+", new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
   </div>
</div>
```

в css:

```
.fluid-block {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```
.col-md-12 {
  background-color: #4682B4;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -10px;/* тут свое укажите*/
  margin-right: -10px /* тут свое укажите*/
}
```